# String Encrypted in Java need to Decrypt in Angular 6 using AES-256-GCM

Tags: java, angular, encryption, aes-gcm

I have Encrypted String in Java using AES/GCM/NoPadding.Now I want to decrypt in Angular6. All examples I have found are using AES-CBC, I want to Decrypt with AES-GCM.

Here is my Java code.

```
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;    
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec; 

public class AESGCMEncryptionUtils {
private static final String SALT = "some salt";
private static final int AES_KEY_SIZE = 256; 
private static final int GCM_NONCE_LENGTH = 12; // IV
private static final int GCM_TAG_LENGTH = 16; 
private static final String AES_GCM_ALGORITHM = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
private static final String PBKDF2 = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256"; 
private static final String ALGORITHAM = "AES";

public static SecretKeySpec generateKey() throws Exception
 {
     PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec("some password".toCharArray(),SALT.getBytes(),10000, AES_KEY_SIZE);
     SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBKDF2).generateSecret(spec);
     SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), ALGORITHAM);
     return keySpec;
 }


public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt)
{
    try 
    {
        byte[] nonce = new byte[GCM_NONCE_LENGTH];
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_GCM_ALGORITHM);
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_TAG_LENGTH * 8 , nonce);

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, generateKey(), gcmParameterSpec);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        log.info("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

I need equivalent Decryption logic in Angular6. Please help me on this.

Comment: What have you tried in angular?

Comment: @Yeou, All the examples I have seen are with AES-CBC, so I am not sure how to proceed with GCM.